# Null substitution in SQLite:

Tags: t-sql, sqlite, null, isnull

In Sybase and MSSqlServer TransactSQL, we have a function IsNull(columnName,valueForNull) to return a typed default value when a column value is null. How can I replicate this functionality in SQLite?

Example in TransactSQL:

```
select IsNull(MyColumn,-1) as MyColumn from MyTable
```

If MyColumn is null, this expression will return -1 as the value of MyColumn. Want to do something similar in SQLite.

*(Yes, I know I can write my own wrapper function to handle this - that's not the answer I'm looking for)*

TIA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [ifnull](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull):

```
select ifnull(MyColumn,-1) as MyColumn from MyTable
```

Comment: ifnull(MyColumn,-1) *exactly* answers my question. Still, @Larry Lustig has given us a completely generic SQL solution with no special function at all.

Answer (score 7):

You should use the standard [COALESCE function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce):

```
select coalesce(MyColumn, -1) as MyColumn from MyTable
```

Any database that understands standard ANSI SQL will support COALESCE so using it is a good habit to get into.

Comment: @Mikey: Using a standard SQL function is a hack? Obscure? I think you are rather mistaken. COALESCE is meant to return the first non-NULL value from a set of *values*, the function doesn't know (nor should it) what a column is as it operates on *values*, not *columns*. The above is the expected and idiomatic use of COALESCE and even matches the example in the [PostgreSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/functions-conditional.html#AEN15548). Using a non-standard function is a hack, using a standard SQL function as it is intended to be used is not a hack.

Comment: +1 - I retracted my comment - realized that same thing on the way home - not that it's standard - you can hack the use of a standard language feature - but because it examines a set of values, and a hard coded value is just another value that can be a set member.

Answer (score 3):

The SQL standard way to do this is with CASE:

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN MyColumn IS NULL THEN -1 ELSE MyColumn END FROM MyTable
```

Considerably more verbose than engine-specific IFNULL, ISNULL, NZ functions, but more portable.

(Or, as mu points out, you can use the much better COALESCE for this).

Answer (score 2):

SQLite has the [IFNULL()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull) built-in function which would do what I think you're trying here.